# the same ratio width/height of application

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml, flash-builder

How can I make an application with the same ratio width/height? I have an application with width = 800 height = 600. Its width = 1.33*height and when I change the width to 1024 I want the height to change to 768 automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean your swf change it´s size?
you would need [swffit](http://swffit.millermedeiros.com/) to do it.

if you want to change your content on your movie, you have to calculate the ratio, more or  less like this:

ratio = width/height;
newHeight = newWidth/ratio;
and vice-versa for the width…

Comment: Maybe you are also looking for the ResizeEvent: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/events/ResizeEvent.html